# How to trim/hide file extension and show the file name on the page using PHP?

Tags: php, html, web-development-server

I have created a form where user selects date and option from drop-down menu (which list all files from the path) and submits it. When submitted, user's input is written down to other file in certain format, but also show underneath the form so user can see the final output. Output, in particular contains date followed with the link based on the chosen option (user can make multiple selections).

**Example:**

User selects 08-01-2014 from date picker and `option1.txt` from drop down. Now that has been output to the `file.js`in this format:

```
'08-01-2014' : '<a href="/path/option1.txt" target="_blank"><span>option1.txt</span></a>',
```

and also has been show underneath the form in this format (***option1.txt is underlined as it is a link but do not know if I can underline it here for showing purposes***):

```
08-01-2014 : option1.txt
```

So my question is how can I modify the code that writes down user's input so the code that shows it can read the file and shows `08-01-2014 : option1` without `.txt`.

**PHP code that write down the user's input (*writedown.php*):**

```
<?php
    $pickdate = $_POST['date'];
    $workout = $_POST['workout'];
    $date = '   \''.$pickdate .'\' : \'<a href="../routines/'.$workout.'" target="_blank"><span>'.$workout.'</span></a>\',' .PHP_EOL;
    $file = 'test.js';
// Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new workout to the file
    $current .= $date;
    $current = preg_replace('/};/', "", $current);
    $current = $current.'};';
// Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
    header( "location:index.php" );
?>
```

**PHP code that shows the user's input underneath the form (*index.php*):**

```
<?php
    $file = "test.js";
    $current = file_get_contents( $file );
    $current = preg_replace('/var codropsEvents = {/', "", $current);
    $current = preg_replace('/,/', "<br>", $current);
    $current = preg_replace('/\'/', " ", $current);
    $current = preg_replace('/ /', " ", $current);
    $current = preg_replace('/};/', "", $current);
    //$current = preg_replace('/option1.txt/', "<a href='test.php'>option1</a>", $current);
    echo $current;
?>
```

I tried everything I knew and I could find on internet and the closest I could get is with commented line in the above code

```
//$current = preg_replace('/option1.txt/', "<a href='test.php'>option1</a>",
```

It is working only for the single entry and I have to add manually same line so I can apply it to another entry.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, please don't edit your title as `Solved` this is unnecessary in `StackOverflow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `basename` to get the filename from the full path:

```
$filename = basename($url,'.txt');
```

Where `$url` is the path to your .txt file

Comment: if you look at the code I currently have you'll see that it is writing the file name to the file and I need that to be trimmed basically. I gave examples above as well ... but long story short - 
it will write following: `<a href="filename.txt">filename.txt</a>` and I need it like this: `<a href="filename.txt">filename</a>`
 anyway thank you for the answer it is correct and working but doesn't apply to my problem. @swiss_blade

Comment: I would say eliminate the part that re-reads the file to display the input to the page. Instead, use `basename($workout, '.txt')` to generate a new line with the filename only where you need it. So the line `$date = '   \''.$pickdate .'\' : \'<a href="../routines/'.$workout.'" target="_blank"><span>'.$workout.'</span></a>` will become something like `$out = $pickdate .' : <a href="../routines/'.$workout.'" target="_blank"><span>'.basename($workout,"txt").'</span></a>;` Then you can pass `$out` as a return value, after you make the whole process into a function

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to utilize a regular expression to do the job.

```
$current = preg_replace(
    '/(.+)\.(.{2,3})$/i',
    '<a href="test.php">\1</a>',
    $current
);
```

Comment: code is correct but when I put it in it appears like nothing changed at all. Results are same, but thanks for the answer. @Cobra_Fast